# Hide price & title in store thumbnail dispay?

Tags: title, plugins

I'm setting up a WooCommerce site to sell shirts.  I have the front page (and the "Store" page" set up to show a grid of thumbnails of the shirt designs.  Each item has the price and the title of the design under it by default.  I want to "turn off" showing the title and the price in the store view.  I *DO* want them to appear on the individual product page, after a user clicks on a thubnail to go to the product page.  Since it is a shirt site, I plan to keep uniform pricing so there is no need to have the same $17.95 price showing up under every shirt, and the title isn't really needed since they can read the graphic on the shirts.

So, any idea if this is possible?  Where would I go to turn this feature off?  I'm running the Rustik theme using WooCommerce.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar — found this:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90410/hide-prices-and-checkout-functionality-in-woocommerce/90993#90993

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple solutions. The solution I would recommend is to remove the actions that prints the price & title in the first place. The main reason I suggest programmatically removing the actions is because it is theme independent. These modifications should work for any theme and you don't have to worry about CSS specificity or any of that nonsense.

If you were using a custom theme you could just put a couple of lines into your functions.php file but since you are using a theme that will just override your changes on the next update I suggest [creating your own woocommerce plugin](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/extending/create-a-plugin/). It isn't as scary as it sounds. In fact, I believe this little plugin I just whipped up does everything you need.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My WooCommerce Modifications
Plugin URI: http://woothemes.com/
Description: Modificatinos to my WooCommerce site
Version: 1.0
Author: Patrick Rauland
Author URI: http://www.patrickrauland.com/
License: GPL version 2 or later - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
/*  Copyright 2013  Patrick Rauland

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as 
    published by the Free Software Foundation.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/


/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 **/
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {


    // remove default woocommerce actions
    function my_woocommerce_modifications()
    {
        // hide product price on category page
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);

        // hide add to cart button on category page
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'my_woocommerce_modifications' );


    // remove the title on the category shop page
    function my_woocommerce_title_modifications($title, $id)
    {
        // if we're on the category shop page then return nothing.
        if(in_the_loop() && is_product_category())
        {
            return "";
        }
        return $title;
    }

    add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_woocommerce_title_modifications');

}
```

Here's the [version controlled gist](https://gist.github.com/BFTrick/4996955) if you ever need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can Directly edit functions.php file and put your own function their

```
function remove_loop_button(){
 remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    // hide product price on category page
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
  }
 add_action('init','remove_loop_button');
```

It will remove both add to cart and price

Answer (score 0):

From the notes on [WooCommerce forums](http://www.woothemes.com/support-forum/?viewtopic=84203) (which are free to register) this is possible but it is also theme dependent.

For instance you can hide the price using this bit of custom .css  to hide the price.
    `span.price{display: none;}`

However ... you'll probably have to check that it doesn't hide the Price everywhere.

If you got your theme from WooThemes you can register for the forums and post your own question there.